# SendKeys() is not correctly working for IOS + Safari + Appium + Python

Tags: python, ios, safari, appium

For a web page , There are 2 fields that I'm trying to fill using IOS + Safari + Appium + Python

1. regular input field, sendKeys() actually puts the text but as I soon as I go to another field it goes blank
2. textarea field with a word counter, sames a input field, text gets filled but counter stucks at 0

I also tried using javascript for both cases, still no luck.

Above approach works fine for Android + Chrome